# How to debug "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer"

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I haven't learned about pointers yet so I don't know how to solve the issue entirely. I'm a beginner C++ student seeking any constructive feedback.

I have no idea how to solve my initializers error. I don't know how to work around the comparison between pointer and integer `[-fpermissive];`. I'm at a complete loss, should I just turn my return types back all to integers? I don't think my array elements will work then? and for error 29:46, I have no idea what I'm missing or where I need to place a ";".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Correct Answers for exam
  const int numberOfAnswers = 10;
  char correctAnswers[numberOfAnswers] = {"A", "D", "B", "B", "C",
                                          "B", "A", "B", "C", "D"};

  // Variables
  int answersRight, answersWrong, passingScore, failingScore;
  answersRight = 0;
  answersWrong = 0;
  passingScore = 8;
  failingScore = 7;
  char userInput;

  // loop for exam questions
  for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; ++counter) {
    cout << "Enter your answer to question" << counter << "." << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
    // Comparing correct answers and tracking right/wrong answers.
    if (userInput == "A", "B", "C", "D") {
      if (userInput == correctAnswers[counter]) {
        answersRight++;
      }
    } else
      (userInput != "A", "B", "C", "D") {
        cout << "Invalid response. You have one more try to answer question "
             << counter << "." << endl;
        cin >> userInput;
      }
    if (userInput == "A", "B", "C", "D") {
      if (userInput = correctAnswers[counter]) {
        answersRight++;
      }
    } else {
      answersWrong++;
    }
  }

  // Display results
  if (answersRight >= passingScore) {
    cout << "Congratulations! You have passed this exam!" << endl;
    cout << "You have answered " << answersRight << " questions right and "
         << answersWrong << " questions wrong." << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "You have failed the exam. Try again to pass!" << endl;
    cout << "You have answered " << answersRight << " questions right and "
         << answersWrong << " questions wrong." << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Down below are the errors I got.

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:82: error: too many initializers for ‘char [11]’
     char correctAnswers[numberOfAnswers]={"A","D","B","B","C","B","A","B","C","D"};
                                                                                  ^
main.cpp:24:27: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
             if(userInput=="A","B","C","D"){
                           ^~~
main.cpp:29:30: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
             }else(userInput!="A","B","C","D"){
                              ^~~
main.cpp:29:46: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
             }else(userInput!="A","B","C","D"){
                                              ^
main.cpp:34:31: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
                 if(userInput=="A","B","C","D"){
                               ^~~
```

Comment: Well, read the error message: `ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer`. So the problem, clearly, is that you are attempting such a comparison. I know, you think you are comparing a character to a character. But `char`, in C++, is an integer type - this should be covered very early on in whatever it is you are using to learn C++ from. So then, if `userInput` is the integer in this comparison, what must be the pointer? Do you understand why that is a pointer?

Comment: "for error 29:46" To make sure you understand: the `29` means the line in the code where the error is being detected, and the `46` means the character position on that line where the error is being detected.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please try to use meaningful titles here if you can, "how to fix my errors" could apply to most of the 19M questions we have here, and finding anything would be tricky. I have tried to add a better title, but you are welcome to edit it again if it could be better - I don't do C++. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is not a _bug_ but a _compilation error_! A bug is a error in your program that occurs at _runtime_. Since it's not a bug, you can't talk about debugging. Yes, using the correct terms for things is important in this line of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems - first, in all of those lines marked with errors, where you have `"` you actually want `'`. The double quotes create string literals, whereas what you actually want are character literals.

Second, the comma operator doesn't work the way you seem to think it does. You need, for example:

```
    if (userInput == 'A' ||
        userInput == 'B' ||
        userInput == 'C' ||
        userInput == 'D') {
```